# Android ListView: List item with buttons

Tags: android, json, listview, listitem

I am parsing json and creating list. After that i have setOnItemClickListener and everything works. 
ListItems are with buttons. In my item layout i have put :

> android:onClick="myClickShare"

and then i've created method in my class to share title.

```
public void myClickShare(View v) {              
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(
                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = ________________________________________;
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "Subject Here");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                shareBody);
        startActivity(sharingIntent);                
}
```

What i wont to do is to find string of that item and put it in shareBody.
I've tried to put:

> Data.get(position).get(TAG_NAME)

but it can't find position of that item (i understand that i dont have list in my method so it wont work)

Can anyone help?

Comment: set onClick to button inside `getView()` method of adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `getView()` method of adapter

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // call share method here   

             myClickShare(v);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

While parsing and setting the name for list items also set the tag as String object inside getView method in adapter for that view.

Then you can use this as

```
public void myClickShare(View v) {              
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(
                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = v.getTag();
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "Subject Here");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                shareBody);
        startActivity(sharingIntent);                
}
```